# Problems syncing between pouch and a couchdb with server authentication

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I'm having problems syncing between pouch and a couchdb with server authentication (no users or roles at database level).
I'm using:

```
Pouch.replicate(src, target, options, function (err, changes) {
 where src= 'default_client' and
 target = `'http://user:password@myhost:5984/default_client'`
```

I get an error `object object { status:0}`

and also

NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed - `http://myhost:5984/default_client/`
I'm using couchdb 1.3 with cors enabled for all origins.

Can anyone shed any light on this or give me some other things to try?  Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a wild guess, not really an answer, but I was looking at my CouchDB settings in Futon today and noticed the `credentials: false` setting:

[image: "credentials" setting]

This setting doesn't appear to be well documented, currently all it says is "TODO" on the [CouchDB wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/CORS#Credentials). It seems like it might be related though, so it's something to look at. Perhaps try pinging the #couchdb IRC channel [on freenode](http://freenode.net/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about changing cors credentials : false, I have tried setting to true and I am still getting the same error.
Is what I trying to do out of the ordinary, it seems that it should be the most common usage?

Comment: @user2515635 I'm not sure how common it is, now that I look, I see there are some open issues on github about this: https://github.com/daleharvey/pouchdb/pull/791, it just needs to get merged in.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar errors until I configured CORS adequately in CouchDB. This is described from a PouchDB perspective in the [PouchDB Getting Started guide](http://pouchdb.com/getting-started.html), and from the CouchDB perspective in the [CouchDB Wiki CORS page](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/CORS).

I have:

```
>curl -X GET http://username:password@127.0.0.1:5984/_config/cors
{"origins":"*","credentials":"true","headers":"accept, authorization, content-type, origin"}
```

As methods are not configured, I take it that methods are unrestricted.